# pandas - creating a stacked plot of size n

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame that looks like such:

```
                  1         2         3         4    5    6    7    8   9   10 ...  15  16  17   18  19  20  21  22  23  24
Date                                                                           ...                                         
1990-01-02  0.971710  0.027471  0.000819  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0   0 ...   0   0   0  0.0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1990-01-03  0.966265  0.032919  0.000815  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0   0 ...   0   0   0  0.0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1990-01-04  0.970886  0.028280  0.000833  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0   0 ...   0   0   0  0.0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1990-01-05  0.969092  0.030065  0.000842  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0   0 ...   0   0   0  0.0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1990-01-08  0.970326  0.028856  0.000817  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0   0 ...   0   0   0  0.0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1990-01-09  0.969999  0.029176  0.000825  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0   0 ...   0   0   0  0.0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

And I want to create a stacked plot, with my y axis being 0 to 1, and the plot always reaches the upper bound of the y axis (because the sum of all the non-nan columns horizontally will always be 1). While a lot of my columns have nans, I want my plot to function as if every column could have some value. I attempted this with the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 3))
ax.stackplot(df.index, df, labels=list(df.columns))
ax.set_title('Combined debt growth over time')
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
ax.set_ylabel('Total debt')
ax.set_xlim(xmin=df.index[0], xmax=df.index[-1])
fig.tight_layout()
```

However, I get the following error on the second line of the code above:

```
{ValueError}operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7222,) (24,)
```

Do I have to manually specify every column? Is there any smart way to simply pass in multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `matplotlib.pyplot.stackplot` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stackplot.html), the first argument is expected to have dimension `N` and the second to have dimension `MxN`, so it's expecting every row to have the dimension `N`, but `df.index` returns an object of shape `(7222,)` (since `df` has shape `(7222, 24)`). You can see this in action in the below example if you switch `df.index` and `df.columns` (as I have).

The easy solution here is to simply transpose the `DataFrame`. This will then give `matplotlib` what it is expecting for the stackplot arguments.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[0.971710, 0.027471, 0.000819, 0.0], 
                   [0.966265, 0.032919, 0.000815, 0.0],
                   [0.970886, 0.028280, 0.000833, 0.0], 
                   [0.969092, 0.030065, 0.000842, 0.0], 
                   [0.970326, 0.028856, 0.000817, 0.0], 
                   [0.969999, 0.029176, 0.000825, 0.0]])
df.index = {"row 1", "row 2", "row 3", "row 4", "row 5", "row 6"}
df.columns = {"column 1", "column 2", "column 3", "column 4"}
plt.stackplot(df.columns, df, labels=list(df.index))
plt.title("Original")
plt.show()
t = df.transpose()
plt.stackplot(t.columns, t, labels=list(t.index))
plt.title("Transposed")
plt.show()
```

[image: Untransposed dataframe with index and column switched in stackplot]

[image: Transposed dataframe result]